# Changing URLs while moving project from development server to live server

Tags: asp.net, url

This is relatively a noob question.

While developing a ASP.Net website, if I am referring to a resource with ResolveUrl() method, it works on either live server or dev server but not on both, based on the Url provided. 
For example, if my code tries to pick a resource with below code, it works on live server but not on development server as JScript.js is not under `http://localhost:xx/Assets` but is under `http://localhost:xx/ApplicationName/Assets`.

```
<script src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/Assets/JScript.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In order to make it work on both servers, I have to keep changing the URL according to the server I am working on.

I have been suffering this annoying problem for sometime but kept ignoring it.

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want them to both be under the same application path, in Visual Studio go to your web projects properties, click on web and change the "Virtual Path" to match your production application name.

Comment: Tried changing the Virtual Path from `/MyIntranet` to `/` but yet the file is not picked.

Comment: If you look url/source of the page, is it now showing the application name ?  On your local dev box, what is the working path to "JScript.js" ?

Comment: Now in Url box in browser, I dont see the application name but the JScript.js still doesn't load. This is my code - `<script src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/Assets/JScript.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>`. When I view source, I should have something like this `<script src="/Assets/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` but I have this `<script src='' type="text/javascript"></script>`. 
This is where I have my JScript.js file `~/Assets/`. Why cant it load?

Comment: change that # to a = and your problems is fixed (eg. <%= %> ).

Comment: Thanks a lot... it worked Zachary. Thanks for your time. Please post your whole answer separately, I shall mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in my comments above, you want to use a **<%= %>** vs. **<%# %>** to render an inline expression.  You only use the hash symbol for inline data binding.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not be the out-the-box way, but I use these to make sure URLS are corect within my applications without issues. with these available in my Page/View's base classes...

```
public static string ApplicationRootUrl()
        {
            string port = String.Empty;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"].ToString() != "80" && HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"].ToString() != "443")
            {
                port = String.Concat(":", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"].ToString());
            }

            string protocol = "http://";

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT_SECURE"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT_SECURE"] != "0")
            {
                protocol = "https://";
            }

            return String.Concat(protocol, String.Concat(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host, port, HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath, '/').Replace(@"//", @"/").ToLower());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Expands a virtual URL to an absolute URL using the current application root url
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url"></param>
        public static string ExpandUrl(string url)
        {
            if (url.Trim().StartsWith("~"))
            {
                return String.Concat(ApplicationRootUrl(), url.Substring(1).Replace("//", "/"));
            }

            if (url.Trim().StartsWith("www", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return String.Concat("http://", url);
            }

            return url;
        }
```

Comment: For some reason, I beleive there will be a better way Mark. May be change in config file or similar. I shall try your code how ever. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try making `http://localhost:xx/ApplicationName` a virtual app on the DEV machine.  That way ~/Assets will be in the root of the app on both PROD and DEV

Basically, the "Assets" directory needs to be in the root of your App, so you need to make the parent of "Assets" the App root on both Dev and PROD.

Comment: I am not running my app on IIS. I am using development server that comes with VS.